# UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey returns extremely small value

Tags: xcode, swift, uikeyboard

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue().size
    let animationDurationValue = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    var animationDuration : NSTimeInterval = 0
    animationDurationValue.getValue(&animationDuration)

    self.keyboardDelegate?.keyboardWillShowWithSize(keyboardSize, andDuration: animationDuration)
  }
```

In my program, I try to reposition my view when keyboard appears using the function above. With  the same way of getting keyboard animation duration in my objective-c code. This one gives me the following status:

```
duration 5.18065378653631e-315
```

This is an abnormally small value. Where have I done wrong? Please help!

EDIT: For complete code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc protocol LPKeyboardViewControllerDelegate {
  func keyboardWillShowWithSize(size:CGSize, andDuration duration:NSTimeInterval)
  func keyboardWillHideWithSize(size:CGSize,andDuration duration:NSTimeInterval)
}

/**
This view controller will move up its view when a keyboard appears in its view
*/
class LPKeyboardViewController: UIViewController {
  var keyboardDelegate: LPKeyboardViewControllerDelegate?

  // MARK: - Lifecycle
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    println("Start listening to keyboard")
  }

  func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue().size
    let animationDurationValue = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    var animationDuration : NSTimeInterval = 0
    animationDurationValue.getValue(&animationDuration)

    self.keyboardDelegate?.keyboardWillShowWithSize(keyboardSize, andDuration: animationDuration)
  }

  func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue().size
    let animationDurationValue = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber
    var animationDuration : NSTimeInterval = animationDurationValue.doubleValue

    self.keyboardDelegate?.keyboardWillHideWithSize(keyboardSize, andDuration: animationDuration)

  }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The docs state that the object for this key is an `NSNumber` so you don't have to jump through the hoops you are you can just do

```
let animationDurationValue = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber
let animationDuration      = animationDurationValue.doubleValue
```

Comment: while tried so, it still give me `5.18065378653631e-315`. Same value as previous one. I can give you entire code